HTTP Server Unknown HTTP Response Code (301):http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/runtime-shared-released/3.9.0/site/content.xml
The same was working fine, not sure when I was trying to load my target today, faicing this 301 respose code.
Looks like it is moved to another place.
Please help.
Thanks in adavance.
we have eclipse based application and we use this url to load our target.

Do you mean "target platform" by "target"? That site is still there but doesn't have a context.xml. Try just https://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/runtime-shared-released/3.9.0/ for the target platform.

A 301 response usually includes where the resource was moved to in another header.

Hello greg-449,
when I try this getting this error-
No repository found at https://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/runtime-shared-released/3.9.0/.

got resolved after replacing http to https -
https://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/runtime-shared-released/3.9.0/site
Thanks
